# Can Cobalt Release 11 be built with C++ compiler before c++11?

Tags: cobalt

In Cobalt Release 11 branch, some code use C++11 features. It seems not compatible with compiler before c++11.

For example, starboard/common/optional.h use std::move as below:

```
  optional(optional&& other) {  // NOLINT(build/c++11)
    if (other.engaged_) {
      SetValue(std::move(other.value()));
    } else {
      InitializeAsDisengaged();
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to make Cobalt built with compiler earlier than C++11?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cobalt 9 is the last version of Cobalt that can be built with C++03-conformant compiler.

Cobalt team made a decision to switch to C++11 to allow easier adoption of latest versions of third-party libraries. In particular, the biggest dependency for Cobalt 11 is SpiderMonkey 45 which uses C++11.

Cobalt team recommends Clang 3.6+ or GCC 4.9+.